# Displaying a collection of controls in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I want to display something like the following :-

[image]

Each row is about a process (information like PID, Parent etc.). User can check the `checkbox` and click Launch button to get some dynamic details about that process.

The problem is that `CheckedListBox` control doesn't allow more than one columns and other controls like `ListView` (which allow multiple columns) don't allow controls like `checkbox` to be embedded in a columns.

I want to know if there is a control which will allow me to have a list of custom controls where each custom control contains a `checkbox`, `Some Text` and `Some Dynamic Text`.

How can this be achieved in Windows Forms? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WinForms table control that can contain other UI controls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702101/winforms-table-control-that-can-contain-other-ui-controls)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use either of these options:

- **DataGridView**  ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65673845/3110834))
  You can use [`DataGridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/datagridview-control-windows-forms?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to show multiple columns of different types, including `TextBox`, `Label`, `CheckBox`, `ComboBox`, `Image`, `Button`, `Link`. You also can customize appearance of the grid by custom painting or adding new custom column types.
- **UserControl**
  You can create a [composite control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/developing-a-composite-windows-forms-control?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) or `UserControl` containing any other controls which you need and use it as a row template, then you can show all rows by hosting multiple instance of that user control in a `Panel` or [`FlowLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/flowlayoutpanel-control-overview?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).
- **TableLayoutPanel**  ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65673845/3110834))
  You can use a [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-windows-forms?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) containing multiple columns and rows. Each cell of `TableLayoutPanel` can host a control.
- **DataRepeater**
  You can use a [`DataRepeater`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/cc488279(v=vs.120)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) control to create a row template and show a list of rows using that template.

#### Example 1 - DatGridView

If you want to use data binding and show specific controls including `TextBox`, `Label`, `CheckBox`, `ComboBox`, `Image`, `Button`, `Link` a row, `DataGridView` is great. It's customize-able and you can add some other different column types or customize painting of the grid or benefit from wide range of useful events for validating and so on.

In following image you can see a `DataGridView` with `RowHeaderVisible` and `ColumnHeaderVisible` set to `false` to act like a List of fields without header:

[image]

#### Example 2 - UserControl

If you need custom control to host more complicated controls or having more control on components or show them in a different layout than columns, you can create a `UserControl` hosting your components, then:

- If you only want top-down flow, Use a `Panel` and add your user control to it with `Dock` property of control set to `Top`.
- If you may want flows other than top-down Use a `FlowLayoutPanel` to add instances of your control to it.

Create a `UserControl`

[image]

Add instances of it to your `Panel` or `FlowLayoutPanel`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) container.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if there is a control which will allow me to have a
>   list of custom controls where each custom control contains a checkbox,
>   Some Text and Some Dynamic Text.

One option could be that you create the following as a separate user control,

[image]

...and as container control use container like `FlowLayoutPanel` and keep adding the user control into the `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Make sure that the direction of `FlowLayoutPanel` is set TopDown

```
this.FlowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
```