# C# ScrollBar in TableLayoutPanel with FlowLayouts

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, tablelayoutpanel, flowlayoutpanel

I have TableLayoutPanel with one row and six columns. I'm adding for each column one FlowLayoutPanel. In FlowLayoutPanels I'm adding dynamically controls. 
I can't add controls directly to TableLayoutPanel becouse adding and deleting is too slow for many rows (removing controls from row and then moving controls from rows below one row up).
But when I'm adding controls to FlowLayoutPanel, TableLayoutPanel doesn't show ScrollBar.

What I have is:
**TableLayoutPanel:** 1 row, 6 cols, DockStyle:Fill, AutoScroll:True
**FlowLayoutPanel:** DockStyle:Fill, FlowDirection:TopDown, WrapContents:False

ScrollBar must show in TableLayoutPanel.

Sample code (I don't think that it helps, rest is set in visual mode):

```
// create controls
CheckBox control1 = new CheckBox();
ComboBox control2 = new ComboBox();
ComboBox control3 = new ComboBox();
ComboBox control4 = new ComboBox();
ComboBox control5 = new ComboBox();
CheckBox control6 = new CheckBox();

control1.AutoSize   = false;
control1.CheckAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

control3.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
control3.Enabled       = false;

control4.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
control4.Enabled       = false;

control5.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
control5.Enabled       = false;

control6.AutoSize   = false;
control6.CheckAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
control6.Enabled    = false;

// add to float layout panels
this.flayControl1.Controls.Add( control1 );
this.flayControl2.Controls.Add( control2 );
this.flayControl3.Controls.Add( control3 );
this.flayControl4.Controls.Add( control4 );
this.flayControl5.Controls.Add( control5 );
this.flayControl6.Controls.Add( control6 );
```

And image, as you see, no scrollbar on left, but controls are hiding at the end (TableLayoutPanel is control with borders):
[image]

Comment: It's better to share a simple code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: updated, I don't think that it helps...

Comment: What's the role of `TableLayoutPanel`? Why not simply use a `Panel`?

Comment: Because of columns, I'm passing percentage values, each control is in separate column.

Comment: So I think you need to update both code and screenshot, because neither of them shows what you described in the above comment  - Or remove the code because it really don't help :)

Comment: And why you don't use a `DataGridView`?

Comment: What kind of controls do you want to show in the panel?

Comment: CheckBoxes, ComboBoxes and TextBoxes. It was working when I creating rows and putting controls directly to rows, but It was slow. Here FlowLayoutPanel is from Top to Down, not from Left to Right.

Comment: So it seems you need `DataGridView`. Hope you find this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32759588/3110834) helpful. Let me know if you have any question about the answer.

Comment: Yea, thanks! I created `FlowLayoutPanel` and then created `TableLayoutPanel` for each `FlorLayoutPanel` "row". Now it works. I cannot use `DataGridView` because I have custom `ComboBox` control. Thanks again for targeting me to the solution.

Comment: You're welcome :) The important thing is that, you made it work :)

Comment: You can kindly vote for helpful answers, it's not compulsory at all, but helps future readers to find useful answer more simple:)

Comment: Also you can edit the question or post your answer to help future readers with same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **Reza Aghaei**, I solved it by this way:

I created `FlowLayoutPanel` and then, I created `TableLayoutPanel` for each row in `FlowLayoutPanel`.

```
int pad1, pad2, height = 28;

FlowLayoutPanel panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
panel.AutoScroll = true;
panel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
panel.WrapContents = false;

for( int x = 0; x < 10; ++x )
{
    TableLayoutPanel table = new TableLayoutPanel();
    table.Width = panel.Width;

    // controls
    CheckBox control1 = new CheckBox();
    ComboBox control2 = new ComboBox();
    ComboBox control3 = new ComboBox();
    TextBox  control4 = new TextBox();
    TextBox  control5 = new TextBox();
    CheckBox control6 = new CheckBox();

    // columns and rows number
    table.ColumnCount = 6;
    table.RowCount    = 1;

    // row height
    table.RowStyles.Add( new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, height) );

    // widths of columns
    table.ColumnStyles.Add( new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 5.0f ) );
    table.ColumnStyles.Add( new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 24.0f) );
    table.ColumnStyles.Add( new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 20.0f) );
    table.ColumnStyles.Add( new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 22.0f) );
    table.ColumnStyles.Add( new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 24.0f) );
    table.ColumnStyles.Add( new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 5.0f ) );

    // fill
    control1.Dock = control2.Dock = control3.Dock = control4.Dock =
    control5.Dock = control6.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    // margin
    pad1 = (height - control2.Height) / 2;
    pad2 = height - control2.Height - pad1;

    control2.Margin = control3.Margin = new Padding( 2, pad1, 2, pad2 );

    // textboxes margin
    pad1 = (height - control4.Height) / 2;
    pad2 = height - control4.Height - pad1;

    control4.Margin = control5.Margin = new Padding( 2, pad1, 2, pad2 );

    // add elements to TableLayoutPanel
    table.Controls.Add( control1, 0, 0 );
    table.Controls.Add( control2, 1, 0 );
    table.Controls.Add( control3, 2, 0 );
    table.Controls.Add( control4, 3, 0 );
    table.Controls.Add( control5, 4, 0 );
    table.Controls.Add( control6, 5, 0 );

    // add table to FlowLayoutPanel
    panel.Controls.Add( table );
}
```

This code creates 10 rows in `FlowLayoutPanel`.