# Remove() function seems only removes a couple of controls at a time

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to remove multiple controls at a time (textboxes and checkboxes) in a windows form application. Basically, I have a row of textboxes and a corresponding checkbox. When the "delete rows" button is clicked, it should remove all rows that have been selected. But it only seems to remove two or three at a time (the same two or three in each row, but there doesn't seem to be any reason it selects those same two or three). I've attached a couple of screenshots showing what is happening.

Here I've selected a couple of rows:
[image]

After hitting delete once:
[image]

After hitting delete twice:
[image]

This just shows the names of each element. As you can see, the names are the same in each row:
[image]

Here is the relevant code:

```
//Gets a list of all ticked checkboxes
public List<string> checkForChecked()
{
    var allCheckboxes = tabPage1.GetAllControlsOfType<CheckBox>();
    int count = allCheckboxes.Count<CheckBox>();
    List<string> checkedChecks = new List<string>();
    foreach(Control c in tabPage1.Controls)
    {
        if(c is CheckBox && ((CheckBox)c).Checked)
        {
            checkedChecks.Add(c.Name.ToString());
        }
    }
    return checkedChecks;
}

//The button click. Loop through elements and remove ones with the right name
private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> toDelete = checkForChecked();
    foreach (var val in toDelete)
    {
        foreach (Control item in tabPage1.Controls.OfType<Control>())
        {
            if (item.Name == val.ToString())
            {
                tabPage1.Controls.Remove(item);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a windows form app, no asp or other web technology.

Comment: The answer depends on the structure which you use to host controls. In general, it's better to use a `DataGridView` for such task. You don't need to layout controls yourself. As an alternative you can use a `UserControl` hosting some checkbox and text boxes and put multiple user controls docked in a panel. For example take a look at this post: [Displaying a collection of controls in Windows Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32759588/3110834)

Comment: Also your code has some problems. For example in `checkForChecked` you find just checked check box names, and then in `button2_Click` you try to remove controls having same names. Those names belong to check boxes not other controls.

Comment: Why you return strings (names of controls) instead of references to controls that need to be deleted?

Comment: You could also give a try to the [DataRepeater control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488279.aspx) from the [Visual Basic Power Packs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488277.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's a common error of removing items from a collection while enumerating it. For example:

```
foreach (Control c in Controls)
    Controls.Remove(c);
```

will remove only half of the controls and leave every second control.

Some of the common solutions to the general problem are:

- removing items in reverse order starting from the end of the collection
- removing the first found item until no items found
- enumerating a copy of the collection

In your case, both methods can be combined to something like this ( [`.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find) returns `Control[]` ) :

```
foreach (var cb in tabPage1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
    if (cb.Checked)
        foreach (var c in tabPage1.Controls.Find(cb.Name, false))
            tabPage1.Controls.Remove(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something more like:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<CheckBox> CheckedBoxes = new List<CheckBox>();
        foreach (CheckBox cb in tabPage1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
        {
            if (cb.Checked)
            {
                CheckedBoxes.Add(cb);    
            }
        }
        foreach (CheckBox cb in CheckedBoxes)
        {
            string cbName = cb.Name;
            cb.Dispose();
            // ... probably more code in here to find the other controls
            // ... in the "row" based on "cbName"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating the controls collection and removing a control, which effects the index of every item in the collection every time you call the Remove() method. This probably messes with your iterator in the foreach, thus the 'skipping' behavior. When removing from any controls collection it is best not to be iterating it at the same time. Moreover, when looping on a Controls collection where you are removing items, code your loops as iterators working backwards.

```
    for (var i=Parent.Controls.Count-1; i >=0; i--)
    {
         if (someCondition) Parent.Controls.Remove(Parent.Controls[i]);
    }
```

Here is a bit cleaner version of your code. The list returned from the CheckForChecked method is now a list of controls which is easier to use than a list of the controls names.

In the remove, we are iterating the list of things to delete, not the controls collection from which we are deleting.

```
     //Gets a list of all ticked checkboxes
     public List<Control> CheckForChecked()
        {
            var tabPage1 = new TabPage();
            var results = new List<Control>(0);
            results.AddRange(from Control c in tabPage1.Controls
                             where c is CheckBox && (c as CheckBox).Checked
                             select c);
            return results;
        }

      //The button click. Loop through elements and remove ones with the right name
      private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
      {
          var toDelete = CheckForChecked();
          var tabPage1 = new TabPage();

          foreach (var val in toDelete.Where(val => tabPage1.Controls.Contains(val)))
          {
              tabPage1.Controls.Remove(val);
          }
      }
```

Hope this helps someone.