# WindowsForm custom DataGridViewColumn

Tags: winforms, custom-controls, datagridviewcolumn

I have a `Windows Form` application where I need to represent in a `DataGridView` or `ListView` a list of items which consist of two label and an image. The text of the labels and the image depends on the property values of the object which the row refers to.
Reading many topics it seems that it's easier with the `DataGridView` defining a new type of column. I followed [this topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80(v=vs.100).aspx) and [this ones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fb61s43(v=vs.100).aspx) but I can't reach the desired output.

Do you have any suggestions or idea?
Thanks!

Comment: To show *two labels and an image* you don't need custom column types. You need to add two `DatGridViewTextBoxColumn` and ine `DataGridViewImageColumn` to `DataGridView.Columns`.

Comment: I want that everything is shown on one column as one item.

Comment: So you can use a read-only `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` and using `CellPainting` event draw what you need.

Comment: Also as an alternative, you can use a `UserControl` hosting two Labels and on `PictureBox` and show a list of your custom user controls in a `Panel`. Also as another alternative, you can use a `DataRepeater` control to show desired layout.

Comment: You may find this post useful: [Displaying a collection of controls in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759540/displaying-a-collection-of-controls-in-windows-forms)

Comment: Thanks! It seems exactly what I'm looking for. I'm going to try what is suggested!