# How can I call same function using different elements like, buttons, textboxs...etc in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this function that has different elements like buttons, textBoxes, dateTimePickers and comboBoxs. [Image of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcK5N.png) for better understanding.

```
private void openLecture (object sender)
    {

        string url = "https://zoom.us/j/" + textLectureLink.Text;

        //run it once
        if (!initialized)
        {
            //Compare time and date to open lecture link
            if (nowDate == calenderDatePicked.Text && nowTime == textLectureTime.Text
            && ampm == comboAMPM.Text)
            {
                try //Open Website
                {
                    initialized = true; // to run it once
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url); //Open link
                 
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    initialized = true; // to run it once
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Click refresh and try again.");
                    
                }
            }
        } 
   
    }
```

I want to execute this function using different type of elements and not copying it to each of them. is there a way?

Comment: Can you pass the text and the date?

Comment: The simpliest way would be to refactor each event methods to pass the controls `calenderDatePicked`, `textLectureTime` and `comboAMPM` to that method

Comment: That's rather a question for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The easiest way is to create UserControl that contains one meeting input fields row and a button action, then just duplicate as many times as you need.

Comment: [Displaying a collection of controls in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32759588/3110834) - A DataGridView or a UserControl may help here. Each group of the controls should represent a model and the validation should be done against the model.